# Set xAxes labels to format YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss in Chart.js

Tags: date, time, chart.js, momentjs, vue-chartjs

I have the following Bubble chart generated in Chart.js. Note the xAxes labels are already date objects.

[image]

Here is the current configuration of the xAxes.

```
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    type: 'time',
    time: {
      unit: 'second',
    }
  }],
```

How can I display the xAxes labels in format `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use property `displayFormats` according to [Display Formats](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#display-formats) from Chart.js documentation. See [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) for the allowable format strings.

```
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    type: 'time',
    time: {
      unit: 'second',
      displayFormats: {
        second: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
      }
    }
  }]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I previously tried that but it does not work. It gives me timestamps like `12AM`, `1AM`, `2AM`... It does not display `YYYY-MM-DD` and the time format is not `HH:mm:ss`

Comment: I updated my answer, forgot to add property `unit: 'second'`